What is the concept used to define tables related among them in a kind of package?
Consider the following Figure available on MySQL Workbench: Visual Database Design

Question:

What is the concept used to define tables related among them in a kind of package?

I want to know that concept/term to learn its respective syntax. Thus if is used other GUI such as DBeaver I want see the same structure. Of course I am assuming the colors are define by the GUI randomly
Furthermore: Is that syntax portable to other DB providers? PostgreSQL, H2, etc
Note I know about the CREATE TABLE ... syntax, but how to define each one in a custom "package"?

that is unreadable

Each "package" is an entity while number of tables in it is a result of normalization

@nbk "that is unreadable" .... what do you mean with that?

@Kondybas ... thank you I am going to do a research about "Entity" in SQL world ... that term is more related with ORM such as: JPA/Hibernate

@ManuelJordan the image

Information Engineering methodology would call those big coloured boxes enclosing several entity types a "subject area." Erwin uses the same name. Dbeaver fakes it by using Notes instead of having a dedicated object.
A subject area is a logical, modelling concept. It is implemented in a database as a schema.

Thank You - what is the concept of "that"? Subject area? In the same way I use Google to define a search such as "mysql create table tutorial" ... here what would be?: "mysql create subject area tutorial"? ... it seems DBeaver either works or interprets that in other way

I do not fully understand your comment but have added what I think you are asking.

Thanks for the clarification - I did do a research in the web and seems it is directly a feature according with the GUI tool itself. Thus it seems "subject area" does not have its own syntax in DDL to let create it and group any tables to reflect all this in any GUI.
